# Starting a paragraph with a big letter

Tags: lettrine

[image]

I want to type my thesis with this style. How can I do this in latex?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With the `lettrine` package and some enhancements.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}
\lettrine[findent=2pt]{\fbox{\textbf{T}}}{ }his thesis deals with some aspects of the Hamiltonian 
formulation of quantum field theory, in particular light-front Hamiltonian field theory. 
Light-front Hamiltonian field theory\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`lettrine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) package. Here is a very basic example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\begin{document}
\lettrine{O}{nce} upon a time
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not familiar with this package, but [its documentation](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/lettrine/doc/lettrine.pdf) shows many possibilities of customization.